# ElasticSDL query using multiple "terms" and one list

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to form a **query to match all connections from or to a specific IP addresses.**
My logs contain SRC_ip and DST_ip.

I do not want to use two queries or duplicate parts of query too much, because it would be very long and not so clear to edit.

Example, how to achieve what I need for IP addresses 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2 is below. This query is working fine, but in case I want to check hundreds of IPs, it would be too long and not so easy to edit frequently.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "src_ip": "1.1.1.1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "dst_ip": "1.1.1.1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "src_ip": "1.1.1.2"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "dst_ip": "1.1.1.2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Ideal solution, which I am looking for would look like this one, but would contain both src_ip or dst_ip addresses from one list in [].

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "src_ip": [
            "1.1.1.1",
            "1.1.1.2",
            .....etc....
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In documentation I did not find any way how to combine **terms**.
Any advice how can I write some nice looking query for both at once?
Something like this:

```
"terms": {
          "src_ip" OR "dst_IP" : [1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2,1.1.1.3,1.1.1.4]
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use a bool query with multiple term queries or you are wanting to write the long array only once in the whole query?

Answer (score 1):

you can leverage on the [Query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query, with something like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "1.1.1.1 OR 1.1.1.2 OR 1.1.1.3",
          "fields": [
            "src_ip",
            "dst_ip"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also keep in mind that there is a dedicated mapping type for IP addresses, which allows you to run range queries (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/range.html) that can save you some boilerplate if you're interested in consecutive addresses.